# Existence of solutions to crossing with the Gliozzi's method

Tags: conformal-field-theory

The [Gliozzi's method](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.3111) in the [Conformal Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_bootstrap) consists in finding approximate solutions to the crossing equation
$$
\sum_{\Delta,L} \mathsf{p}_{\Delta,L} \, \frac{v^{\Delta_\varphi}G_{\Delta,L}(u,v)-u^{\Delta_\varphi}G_{\Delta,L}(v,u)}{u^{\Delta_\varphi}-v^{\Delta_\varphi}}= 1\,.\tag{4}
$$
where $u=\frac{x_{12}^2 x_{34}^2}{x_{13}^2 x_{24}^2},\,v = \frac{x_{14}^2 x_{23}^2}{x_{13}^2 x_{24}^2}$ are the crossing ratios of a four point function $\langle \phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\phi(x_3)\phi(x_4)\rangle$ of a scalar with conformal dimension $\Delta_\varphi$ in a generic CFT, $\mathsf{p}_{\Delta,l}$ are the squared OPE coefficients and $G_{\Delta,L}(u,v)$ are the conformal blocks.

Such approximate solutions are obtained by truncating the sum over $\Delta$ and $L$ to a finite number of terms. The crossing equation can be Taylor expanded around $u = v = 1/2$ thus yielding a single inhomogeneous equation
$$
\sum_{\Delta,L} \mathsf{p}_{\Delta,L} \, \mathsf{f}^{(0,0)}_{\Delta_\varphi,\Delta_L}  = 1\,,\tag{5}
$$
and arbitrarily many homogeneous ones
$$
\sum_{\Delta,L} \mathsf{p}_{\Delta,L} \, \mathsf{f}^{(2m,n)}_{\Delta_\varphi,\Delta_L}  = 0\,,\quad (m,n\in \mathbb{N},\,m+n\neq 0)\,. \tag{6}
$$
Here $\mathsf{f}^{(m,n)}_{\Delta_\varphi,\Delta_L}$ is the $m$th and $n$th derivative of the function defined in $(4)$ evaluated at $u=v=1/2$. Obviously $\mathsf{f}^{(0,0)}_{\Delta_\varphi,\Delta_L}$ is just the function evaluated at $u=v=1/2$. The precise definition is in the paper linked at the beginning but it's not important.

Now the author focuses only on $(6)$ and shows a condition for the existence of nontrivial solutions to that system. Consider the matrix ($i$ labels rows, $j$ columns)
$$
\left(\mathsf{f}^{(m_i,n_i)}_{\Delta_\varphi,(\Delta_L)_j}\right)_{i,j}\,,
$$
where $i$ runs through the various equations kept in $(6)$ and $j$ runs through the operators kept in the truncation. The condition for the existence of a nontrivial solution is that the above matrix must not have full rank. I agree with this statement but then he says that $(5)$ is simply a normalization condition, implying that we could always extend it to a solution of the full crossing equation $(5) + (6)$.

I believe that this is wrong if $(5)$ happens to be a linear combination of some of the equations in $(6)$. In this case indeed $(5)$ reduces to $0=1$. More formally, this is a simple application of [Rouché–Capelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem): the solutions exists only if the matrices
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
\mathsf{f}^{(0,0)}_{\Delta_\varphi,(\Delta_L)_j}\\
\hline
\mathsf{f}^{(m_i,n_i)}_{\Delta_\varphi,(\Delta_L)_j}
\end{array}
\right)\quad \mbox{and}\quad
\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
\mathsf{f}^{(0,0)}_{\Delta_\varphi,(\Delta_L)_j}& 1\\
\hline
\mathsf{f}^{(m_i,n_i)}_{\Delta_\varphi,(\Delta_L)_j} & 0
\end{array}
\right)\,,
$$
have the same rank, and this cannot be if $\mathsf{f}^{(0,0)}_{\Delta_\varphi,(\Delta_L)_j}$ is in the span of $\mathsf{f}^{(m_i,n_i)}_{\Delta_\varphi,(\Delta_L)_j}$.

My question is: how can we make sure that this doesn't happen and thus that we can always extend a solution of the homogeneous system to a solution of the inhomogeneous one? Or, alternatively, I'm asking if there are examples where what I just described actually happens. I expect the solution, if it exists, to rely somehow on the properties of the conformal blocks.

Comment: Derivatives of conformal blocks are linearly-independent functions of $\Delta$ and $L$. You can probably prove this relatively easily by analyzing large-$\Delta$ limit. Because they are also analytic functions of $\Delta$ and $L$, it follows that for generic choice of the operator dimensions the equations are independent. You could worry that it can still happen that for some non-generic choice of operator dimensions you have this problem, and it could be harder to prove that this doesn't happen.

Comment: However, it doesn't seem that such a situation, even if possible, could be physically relevant. For one thing, after truncation you do not expect to recover the exact dimensions, but rather some non-canonical approximation (since the truncation is not canonical). So if you choose a different truncation, you will get another set of dimensions, and avoid this problem.